# jquery/javascript - accessing variables from outside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to use a variable value outside of the function it was defined in. Thought I. just needed to declare the variable outside the function but that doesn't cut it. Gotta be an easy one for those who know?

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xSa2T/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var readOut;
    var readOut2;

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        readOut1 = e.pageX;
        readOut2 = e.pageY;
        $('#var1').html(readOut1);

    });

    $('#var2').html(readOut2);
})​
```

Thanks to all, especially Andy E with the explaination and [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/FrVjd/).

Comment: Try removing 'var' from the variable declaration, as this should make the variables globals, or placing them outside the ready function.  Not confidents enough to put that in an answer though :)  Let me know if it works.  I think the variables are local to the ready() function only.

Comment: What is your problem? Except for the typo (`var readOut;` vs `readOut1 = ...`) your code seems to be working as it should.

Comment: @tom: You're wrong. What you're suggesting will work, it should, however, work as it is now. Implicit globals are not bad. The inner (`mousemove` handler) has access to all variables the `ready` handler has. (Search keywords for more on this: javascript, closures)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning to the variables via a callback function which is registered to an event handler.  This means that when this runs:

```
$('#var2').html(readOut2);
```

`readOut2` has a value of *undefined* because it hasn't been set by the *mousemove* handler function yet.  That handler won't fire until the current queued code stops executing and the user moves their mouse.  You could define a function in the same scope as the variables, and call that function from the *mousemove* handler.

Re: your comments on another answer, you could use a timer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
    var readOut1;
    var readOut2;

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        readOut1 = e.pageX;
        readOut2 = e.pageY;
        $('#var1').html(readOut1);

    });

    window.setInterval(function () { 
        $('#var2').html(readOut2);
    }, 300);
})​;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to track cursor coordinates, check out the updated source code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var readOut1;
    var readOut2;

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        readOut1 = e.pageX;
        readOut2 = e.pageY;
        $('#var1').html(readOut1);
        $('#var2').html(readOut2);
    });

})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xSa2T/2/

Comment: hey thanks, i was using this more as an example. yes i do want to track cursor movements, but want to use the value outside the on mousemove function, which is why i moved the var2 line.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a timing problem.

This line

```
$('#var2').html(readOut2);
```

is gonna get called at document.ready, while the mousemove event hasn't been called yet, so readOut2 will not have a value yet.

Comment: ah yes, how dense of me.
could i use setInterval to constantly update readOut2?

Answer (score 1):

> but want to use the value outside the on mousemove function

As the variables `readOut1` and `readOut2` might not be set before the mousemove event handler is run you will have to call any code that will use these variables from the mousemove handler.

Example:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    readOut1 = e.pageX;
    readOut2 = e.pageY;

    doStuffWithReadOuts(/* possibly passing readouts as arguments instead... */);
});

function doStuffWithReadOuts() {
        $('#var1').html(readOut1);
        $('#var2').html(readOut2);
}
```

Comment: cheers thats pretty helpful. i wonder could the readOut2 display be called off a timer like setInterval instead of mousemove?